# How to decide on the family type for variables with bimodal distribution in GLM?

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-linear-model

so I have a bunch of continuous features to compare between two groups (let's say small & large). These features are not normally distributed and they are significantly different between the groups. Now I want to adjust for the effect of 3 covariates (BMI, age, and wk) but I can't use ANCOVA because they are not normally distributed. So, I want to fit a generalized linear model:  `glm(Feat_129227 ~ BW_group + BMI + AGE + WK, data = Full_dataset, family =??)`,
but the distribution for most of the features looks bimodal, so I am not sure which family or type of distribution to use, can you advise?

[image]

Note, when using a general linear model, the distribution of the residuals was not normal, with Shapiro test p value of 0.0049 and this is qqplot or the residuals.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What aspect of you regression depends on the distribution of the features being normal?

Comment: keep in mind that it's *residuals* that are normally distributed! It's totally OK if you have bimodal responses if you, say, have two clusters of X-variables! Fit a standard linear regression, and look at those residuals before you claim you have non-normal data.

Comment: Possibly related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned in the comments, a linear model does not assume that the *response* is normally distributed, rather that the *error* is. The estimate for the latter is conditional on the fit!

Consider the following simulation example where we know the data-generating mechanism exactly:

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 1E4
age <- runif(n, min=18, max=65)
bmi <- rnorm(n, mean=25, sd=6)
wk <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)

y <- 3.5 + wk + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=0.38)

f <- lm(y ~ age + bmi + wk)
```

In this case `age` and `bmi` are pure noise, and `wk` -- which you didn't provide further details on -- is responsible for a shift in mean. Not only does this data look very convincingly like your sample's density on the left (though I did use a much larger sample size), the normality assumption for the residuals is convincingly met (and here we have the luxury of knowing it to be true):
[image: density + QQ plot]

So, as long as your model can "explain the data" (fit the data-generating mechanism) well enough, as evidenced by sufficiently well-behaved residuals among other things, there is nothing to worry about.

Obviously this is a much simplified example & it remains to be seen if the same is true for your actual sample, but there is no *a priori* reason why a bimodal response would make a standard linear model invalid.

One thing that worries me a bit more is that you included both `BW_group` and `BMI` in your example formula. If these are what I think they are you would expect a significant degree of correlation between both predictors, BMI being a direct function of weight & height.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I should have added that the residuals were not normally distributed, this is why I thought I need a glm. 

So, basically the features are metabolites measured in blood and I want to see if they are significantly different between the two groups (large and small babies) while adjusting for the effect of covariates (maternal BMI, age and gestational week of testing). 

Shapiro testing of the residuals gave me a p value of 0.0049.  I added the qqplot of the residuals to my original post. Can you advise in this case what to do?

Answer (score 3):

GLM (generalised linear model) is a generalisation of OLS (Ordinary least squares) by allowing

- more types of conditional distributions
- wrapping the linear descriptor in a link functions to describe the mean of those distributions

Basically, you model two things

- 1. the variance as a function of the mean $$\sigma_Y^2 = f(\mu_Y)$$
- 2. a non-linear function of the mean as a linear function of the parameters (that non-linear function is called the link function) $$g(\mu_y) = X \cdot \beta$$

In your case you seem to be worried about non-normality of something, but it is unclear whag exactly. In any case

- Your covariates don't need to be normal distributed and neither does the dependent variable. It is the *conditional* distribution of the dependent variable that is assumed to be normal distributed, and even when that assumption is not accurate then OLS might work well.
- GLM models the mean and variance. If you have something like a bimodal distribution, then you might want to use different techniques that address this more in detail.